# change type of a computed column to uncomputed in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have some computed columns in my DB with data. Is there anyway to change type of those columns to uncomputed without dropping and copying their data into new uncomputed columns?

For example I want to change

```
[Fee] AS CONVERT([decimal](19,4),(case when [Quantity]=(0) then (0) else [Price]/[Quantity] end)) PERSISTED,
```

to

```
[Fee] [decimal](26, 16) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us what **concrete database** this is for. `SQL` is just the **query language** but things like this aren't defined in the standard - they are vendor-specific. Please add an appropriate tag, like `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed Columns do not store data in themselves.
When you try to select the column in a query it computes the data and shows you. Also you can not modify computed columns to uncomputed columns.

But you can do this instead:

```
Create Table Temp (ID BigInt, value Computed_Column_DataType)
Go
Insert Temp(ID, Value)
Select ID, ComputedColumnName
       From Your_Table
Go
Alter Table Your_Table Drop Column ComputedColumnName
Go
Alter Table Your_Table Add ComputedColumnName Computed_Column_DataType
Go
Update Your_Table Set ComputedColumnName = A.Value From Temp A Where A.ID = YourTable.ID
```

Comment: Minor typo: The last line should have Your_Table instead of YourTable. (Sorry I couldn't edit the answer - it's saying I need to change at least 6 characters. Hence the comment.)

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer is "it depends." MySQL doesn't even have computed columns. In SQL Server, I don't think it is possible. In Oracle it can be done with `alter table t1 modify fee DECIMAL( m, n )`.

However, even when allowed, the DBMS is probably behind the scenes creating a new column, moving the computed value to the new column, dropping the computed column and renaming new column to computed column name. So even if the conversion is not explicitly allowed, you can still get it done.

Comment: For the record, the latecomers please note that MySQL (5.7.x) also supports [computed columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html).

The accepted answer assumed the computed column is virtual but it could indeed be `STORED` in the case of MySQL, for instance. However, I share @tommcatt thoughts that even in this case MySQL could not simply change the column types without doing all the things (add the new column, copy, delete the old one, rename column) behind the scenes.